# How to right click on the nodes in a d3 tree

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 tree and I want to be able to right click the node so that a new file is opened which lists the children of that node. How do I do this? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by new file? could you post an example that you have?

Comment: a json file that just lists the children of the node

Answer (score 6):

In your code where you are creating the nodes and it's attributes you add...

`.on('contextmenu',/* handler */);`

So an example of this used in code would be...

```
node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on('dblclick', /* handler for double click */ )
        .on('contextmenu', /* handler for right click */ );
```

As for reading in the file which I am assuming is a local text file you can reference

[Javascript - read local text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)

and just call the function you create in the `.on`.

`.on('contextmenu', functionForReadFile);`

Comment: thank you very much, i would like it to open a new json file that lists the children though, not read in a file, if that makes sense

Comment: It sounds like you want to 'create' a new file, can't open a new one if it doesn't exist.  Are you wanting it to show the json data and have it save to a file?